# Mostrar mensaje al cerrar calculadora de Windows abierta desde java

Tags: java, windows

No consigo hacer que java espere a que cierre la calculadora de Windows para mostrar un mensaje de que la aplicacion se ha cerrado. Con el bloc de notas si me funciona este codigo. Pero con la calculadora no.

```js
package Ejercicios;

public class Prac_02 {

 public Prac_02() {
  try {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");
   p.waitFor();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Prac_02();

  System.out.println("Calculadora cerrada con exito");
 }

}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner el System.out.println justo debajo de p.waitFor();? Un saludo.

Comment: Si, el problema es que el codigo no espera a que cierre la calculadora para imprimir el mensaje. Lo imprime siempre, ignorando el waitFor, con el bloc de notas si que espera a que lo cierre para imprimir el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma, como en este ejemplo.

```java
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class ProcessDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         // create a new process
         System.out.println("Creating Process...");
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");

         // cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
         p.waitFor();

         // when you manually close notepad.exe program will continue here
         System.out.println("Waiting over.");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```